# Running Tor relay or exit node entirely from RAM memory using initramfs or Live CD

Tags: security, relays, exit-relays, server-administration

I would like to run several dedicated servers, both relays and exit nodes.  I am concerned about two things:

1. The running server being hacked in a way that compromises the anonymity of user.
2. The machine being breached remotely or locally at the colo where it is running.

It seems running Tor from a CD or DVD and rebooting regularly could address Item 1, however accessing the CD or DVD is extremely slow.

Regarding Item 2, I am thinking it would best to run Tor like a "Live CD" with no hard drive and use the servers memory only so there are no storage devices and reboots start cleanly from unmodifiable media.

I believe it's possible to run a machine out of memory using initramfs but would like do this without wrestling to combine the latest Tor releases with a "Live CD" linux distribution.  Is anyone working on a "Live CD Tor System" that would include to minimal OS necessary to run as relay or exit node and run entirely out of memory?

I've looked at TAILS but it has way more OS than is required.  Thanks if anyone can point me to others working on this or interested in helping. I don't want to repeat the work of others and don't know if others would use such a configuration, though I think it has advantages.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [tor-ramdisk](http://opensource.dyc.edu/tor-ramdisk) or [Torride](https://redmine.koumbit.net/projects/torride) to be what you are looking for.